# Generate paths on n*n grid

Tags: algorithm, multidimensional-array

I have `n*n` grid, where for example `n=10`. I have to fill it with black and white elements. Every black element has to have one, two or three black neighbors. It is not allowed to contain black elements with four or zero neighbors.

How should I build this kind of grid ?

Edit:

To be more specific, it is two-dimensional array built for example with two `for` loops:

```
n = 10
array = [][];
for ( x = 0; x < n; x++ ) {
    for ( y = 0; y < n; y++ ) {
        array[x][y] = rand(black/white)
    }
}
```

This pseudo code builds somethind like:

[image: current]

And what I expect is:

[image: expected]

Comment: Are there any other restrictions?  If that's all you have to do, just stripe it with alternating white and black rows and give it a solid black border.

Comment: Are the cells that lie diagonally also considered neighbours, or just the 4 to the north, east, south and west to it?

Comment: Is it alowed to put just single 2x1 black element on white grid?

Comment: Check my edit.
@ralu it will be better if all the grid will be filled with path - not just 2 elements on the 100 element grid.

Comment: In your expected image, you can reach any black square, starting from any black square, by traversing over only black squares. Is this property true for all the grids you want to generate? Or is it permissible to generate separate "islands", where travel between the two is impossible?

Comment: There is a nice maze-generation demonstration on Wikipedia page for [Prim's algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prim%27s_algorithm).

Comment: @Kevin I'd like to travel between every black square - islands are undesirable.

Comment: A very naive algorithm would be: start with a white grid, add a black cell in a random position, then repeatedly choose at random a white cell adjacent to an existing black cell and turn it black if this wouldn't break the rule, until either it becomes impossible to add any more black cells, or you reach a desired density.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Obviously, you're trying to generate "black path" shapes on a write grid.

So let's just do it.

- Start with a white grid.
- Randomly position some turtles on it.
- Then, while your grid doesn't meet a proper white/black cell ratio, do the following

  - Move each turtle one cell in a random direction and paint it black unless doing so break the "no more than three black neighbors" rule.

Comment: You may add to your description "if no route found, come back to previous" Also, it seems starting from middle gives much better results http://codepad.viper-7.com/FIoJn3

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this python code could be of some use. Its basic idea is to do some sort of breadth first traversal of the grid, ensuring that the blackened pixels respect the constraint that they have no more than 3 black neighbours. The graph corresponding to the blackened part of the grid is a tree, as your desired result seemed to be.

```
import Queue
import Image
import numpy as np
import random

#size of the problem
size = 50

#grid initialization
grid = np.zeros((size,size),dtype=np.uint8)

#start at the center
initpos = (size/2,size/2)

#create the propagation queue
qu = Queue.Queue()

#queue the starting point
qu.put((initpos,initpos))

#the starting point is queued
grid[initpos] = 1


#get the neighbouring grid cells from a position
def get_neighbours(pos):
  n1 = (pos[0]+1,pos[1]  )
  n2 = (pos[0]  ,pos[1]+1)
  n3 = (pos[0]-1,pos[1]  )
  n4 = (pos[0]  ,pos[1]-1)
  return [neigh for neigh in [n1,n2,n3,n4] 
                  if neigh[0] > -1 and \
                     neigh[0]<size and \
                     neigh[1] > -1 and \
                     neigh[1]<size \
         ]


while(not qu.empty()):
  #pop a new element from the queue
  #pos is its position in the grid
  #parent is the position of the cell which propagated this one
  (pos,parent) = qu.get()

  #get the neighbouring cells
  neighbours = get_neighbours(pos)

  #legend for grid values
  #0 -> nothing
  #1 -> stacked
  #2 -> black
  #3 -> white

  #if any neighbouring cell is black, we could join two branches
  has_black = False
  for neigh in neighbours:
    if neigh != parent and grid[neigh] == 2:
      has_black = True
      break

  if has_black:
    #blackening this cell means joining branches, abort
    grid[pos] = 3
  else:
    #this cell does not join branches, blacken it
    grid[pos] = 2

    #select all valid neighbours for propagation
    propag_candidates = [n for n in neighbours if n != parent and grid[n] == 0]
    #shuffle to avoid deterministic patterns
    random.shuffle(propag_candidates)
    #propagate the first two neighbours
    for neigh in propag_candidates[:2]:
      #queue the neighbour
      qu.put((neigh,pos))
      #mark it as queued
      grid[neigh] = 1

#render image
np.putmask(grid,grid!=2,255)
np.putmask(grid,grid<255,0)
im = Image.fromarray(grid)
im.save('data.png')
```

Here is a result setting `size = 50`

[image: black tree over grid, width 50]

and another one setting `size = 1000`

[image: black tree over grid, width 1000]

You can also play with the root of the tree.

Answer (score 1):

With the size that you show here, you could easily go for a bit of a brute force implementation.

Write a function that checks if you meet the requirements, simply by iterating through all cells and counting neighbors.

After that, do something like this:

```
Start out with a white grid.
Then repeatedly:
    pick a random cell
    If the cell is white:
        make it black
        call the grid checking routine.
        if the grid became invalid:
            color it gray to make sure you don't try this one again

do this until you think it took long enough, or there are no more white cells.
then make all gray cells white.
```

If your grid is large (thousands of pixels), you should probably look for a more efficient algorithm, but for a 10x10 grid this will be calculated in a flash.